# Energy and power in a travelling sinusoidal wave

Tags: waves

This stuff is driving me crazy.
Here: http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/AnalyzingWaves.htm
I found that the average kinetic energy per unit length is:
$$ \frac{1}{4}\mu \omega^2 A^2 $$
While here:
http://tonic.physics.sunysb.edu/~dteaney/F09_141/lectures/waves.pdf
it is reported to be
$$ \frac{1}{2}\mu \omega^2 A^2  $$
Which one is right and where can I find a good paper on this?

Comment: If you had read on in your first link you would have found that the equation with a half in it is the average total energy per metre whereas the first equation, as you have stated, the average kinetic energy per metre.